# Use base64 encoded string in url cakephp

Tags: url, cakephp, base64

here is the solution for php [Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

but because of urlencode cakephp problem I cant use it (the solution in there is not good for me)

[Passing an urlencoded URL as parameter to a controller / action at CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750989/passing-an-urlencoded-url-as-parameter-to-a-controller-action-at-cakephp)

Rawurlencode does not work either. Also I cant hash it because I need it to be reversible. Or is there some "reversible" hash function. I know that the meaning of hash is for one way, but like some way to get output similar(so I can use in the url without problems) to md5/sha* but be able to reverse.

**QSN:** how to use base64 encoded string in url to avoid problems, mentioned in the above link.

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Why can't you use any of the solutions provided in the linked questions? "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. Also it would probably help if you'd actually explain the context of this problem, ie where any why do you need send/receive base64 encoded strings in a URL.

Comment: @ndm tks for the comment, when I use urlencode or rawurlencode, opening that page with that url, gives 404 not found error, thats what I mean does not work, which was stated in the second link. I do not know how to explain in a few words so it would make sense.

Comment: Still, there are solutions described for the problem mentioned in the linked questions, so again, why can't you use any of them?

Comment: Use a query param instead of trying anything else for passing this data. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url as well.