# How send parameter format uft8 by GET method?

Tags: php

I encode param as:

```
 $Title="CSVのアップロードに失敗しました。CSV(.zip)ファイルの内容を修正して、再度アップロードをやり直してください。"       ;
 $Title1=urlencode($Title);
```

Value of  $Title1 is:

```
"CSV%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%80%82CSV%28.zip%29%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E5%86%85%E5%AE%B9%E3%82%92%E4%BF%AE%E6%AD%A3%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%80%81%E5%86%8D%E5%BA%A6%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E3%82%84%E3%82%8A%E7%9B%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%80%82"
```

I send param as:

```
 header("Location:".JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_servicemanager&view=i0702'.'&msg='.$msg1."&Title=".$Title1));
```

Why on url : value of Title don't encode:

```
http://localhost:81/joomlandk/index.php/component/servicemanager/?view=i0702&amp;msg=File%20is%20invalid.&amp;Title=CSVă®ă‚¢ăƒƒăƒ—ăƒ­ăƒ¼ăƒ‰ă«å¤±æ•—ă—ă¾ă—ăŸă€‚CSV(.zip)ăƒ•ă‚¡ă‚¤ăƒ«ă®å†…å®¹ă‚’ä¿®æ­£ă—ă¦ă€å†åº¦ă‚¢ăƒƒăƒ—ăƒ­ăƒ¼ăƒ‰ă‚’ă‚„ă‚ç›´ă—ă¦ăă ă•ă„ă€‚
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What is it that you want??? I totally don't get it.

Comment: Where are you looking at the result? What does `JRoute::_` do and what's its output?

Comment: is your php script file utf8 encoded??

Comment: try to pass `false` on the second parameter for `JRoute::_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to properly exchange non-ASCII data is to encode it with [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode). Since Base64 is not completely URL-safe can use `urlencode` and `urldecode` or you can write a function, which produces URL-safe Base64.

I took it from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835352/1401510) by [joeshmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197484/joeshmo):

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
    return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```

With this helper function you can encode your text:

```
$Title = "CSVのアップロードに失敗しました。CSV(.zip)ファイルの内容を修正して、再度アップロードをやり直してください。"       ;
$encoded_title = base64_url_encode($Title);
```

To decode it on the other side, simply do this:

```
$Title = base64_url_decode($_GET['Title']);
```

Comment: Why not use URL encoding instead...?

Comment: @deceze: I thought it would be a little bit overkill. But you are right, `urlencode`/`urldecode` could be used as well.