# PHP: Create a iv. Not working

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I have write a code to encrypt a data with mcrypt. When I create a IV it works BUT when I decrypt it the decrypted text isn't the same as before and it gives me this error:

```
Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize
```

Here is my code when I create a IV:

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($algo, $type), MCRYPT_RAND);
```

The problem is also that it gives a string with unreadable characters.

Here is my code when encrypting:

```
trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt($algo, $pass,
                                  $data, $type, $iv)));
```

And here is for decrypting:

```
trim(mcrypt_decrypt($algo, $pass,
                    base64_decode($data), $type, $iv));
```

The question: Why can't it decrypt so I get the plaintext and why it gives me a error.

**EDIT:**
When I use a EMPTY IV, it works and I get the plaintext, but it still gives me error:

```
Warning: mcrypt_xxxxxx(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize
```

Comment: Don't `trim()` the ciphertext and only `rtrim()` the decrypted plaintext.

Comment: Dosent work, I tried it.

Comment: See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635474/recieving-error-warning-mcrypt-decrypt-the-iv-parameter-must-be-as-long-as-t

Answer (score 0):

> I have write a code to encrypt a data **with mcrypt.**

This never bodes well. (Emphasis mine.)

> When I create a IV it works BUT when I decrypt it the decrypted text isn't the same as before and it gives me this error:
>
> ```
> Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize
> ```
>
> Here is my code when I create a IV:
>
> ```
> $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size($algo, $type), MCRYPT_RAND);
> ```

Do you know what `MCRYPT_RAND` means? It means `rand()`, an insecure random number generator.

Every algorithm that requires an initialization vector (IV) has the following security requirements:

1. Initialization vectors must never repeat.
2. Initialization vectors *must be unpredictable*.

`MCRYPT_RAND` fails at both counts: There are only 2^32 possible outputs from `rand()` and it's predictable.

> The question: Why can't it decrypt so I get the plaintext and why it gives me a error.

The simplest answer is [mcrypt sucks and you should use something else](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong). My recommendations are [here](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/11/choosing-right-cryptography-library-for-your-php-project-guide).