# mcrypt_decrypt: generating an IV on small amount of data gets corrupted result

Tags: php, cakephp, encryption

I have looked at this entry and tested some of the recommendations:  [recieving error Warning: mcrypt_decrypt(): The IV parameter must be as long as the blocksize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635474/recieving-error-warning-mcrypt-decrypt-the-iv-parameter-must-be-as-long-as-t)

I have a very small pdf file (141.06 kb) that was created from a webpage using wkhtmltopdf and encrypted using this function:

```
public function encrypt($data) {
    if ($data !== '') {

        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

        $plaintext_utf8 = utf8_encode($data);
        return base64_encode($iv) . base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, Configure::read('Cryptable.key'), $plaintext_utf8, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

As I mentioned above, I tested some of the recommendations on a SO post and found this:

iv_size = 16

length of iv = 18

Any other larger document encrypted with the same function decrypts properly so what I'm trying to figure out is **how to handle very small files**.  Could it be that when calculating the iv on small amounts of data the result can be unpredictable?

This is the decrypt function:

```
public function decrypt($data, $data2 = null) {
    if (is_object($data)) {
        unset($data);
        $data = $data2;
    }

    if ($data != '') {
        $iv = base64_decode(substr($data, 0, strlen(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)))));
        $data = base64_decode(substr($data, strlen(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)))));

        return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, Configure::read('Cryptable.key'), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

IV size is calculated like this:

```
$this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
```

Before I forget, I'm using CakePHP 2.6.4

Comment: Why do you encode, decode and do string operations on  your IV and key?

Comment: Are you aware that CakePHP ships with encrypting functionality? **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.6.7/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L217**. Also besides the other rather weird stuff, why do you blindly trim on both ends? Are you sure that this doesn't trim away necessary data?

Comment: The reason for the weird stuff is that this is inherited code under which there are hundreds if not thousands of already encrypted files using this method.  Only after adding a new pdf creation of an already existing web form did we notice this.  I don't know much about why Cake's encryption scheme is not used but I believe it had something to do with corruption with docx files.

Comment: Just to clarify, this method works for every other file but the really small ones.