# PHP sending encrypted data via the URL

Tags: php, encryption, base64, url-encoding, mcrypt

I'm trying to send encrypted data over the url to another site (using `file_get_contents("anotherUrl.php?hash=$encryptedString")`. The problem is, sometimes, the encryption contains some special characters, like +, and this causes the decryption to fail.

Here are my encryption / decryption methods:

```
public function encrypt($string, $key)
{
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
}

public function decrypt($encrypted, $key)
{
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
}
```

Here's an example encrypted string which contains a `+`, and I'm guessing that this causes the decryption to fail.

`oWCrVPaS+5GbxcQFc0fulUk/zRAkDD60av4zlPiWskE=`

Any ideas how I should solve this? I've tried to do `urlencode()` and `urldecode()` on the hash, however that also seems to cause the encryption to break. Is there a way to change the encryption algorithm to get it to only return url safe characters?

Comment: Just a side question, why are you performing two successive md5 operations on the key? What do you hope to achieve from that?

Comment: @CPUTerminator Actually I've copied the function exactly as is from another answer here on SO, I've not made any changes to it.

Comment: Ehh... I don't see any point in that. If the key is weak (i.e not from a cryptographically strong random number generator) you should **not** be using `md5` as an key-strengthening algorithm (see `PBKDF#2`, `bcrypt` or `scrypt`). If your key is already strong, you're just wasting processor cycles.

Comment: Where did you get the cryptography code? [It's not secure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30159120/2224584).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Take a look at this thread:

[Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

Essentially you **DO** want to `urlencode()` before sending the string, however you do **NOT** want to `urldecode()` at the other end.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct. It works with one way url encoding. ( There should be no url decode function if its not supposed to be decoded, but that's PHP for you).

Comment: There are plenty of other times where urldecode() is needed, but this is not one of them. Glad to help.

Comment: The `urlencode` is necessary since you are building a *query string* here. On the other side PHP takes that query string and `urldecode`s that for you, writing the result into `$_GET`. This is the reason for the asymmetry. If you were to parse the *query string* yourself, you would also have to do the `urldecode` yourself.

Answer (score 8):

In order to solve this problem I now use the following (after 3 hours of pain), and it works great.

Feel free to copy and paste

```
function encrypt($pure_string) {
    $dirty = array("+", "/", "=");
    $clean = array("_PLUS_", "_SLASH_", "_EQUALS_");
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $_SESSION['iv'] = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $_SESSION['encryption-key'], utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $_SESSION['iv']);
    $encrypted_string = base64_encode($encrypted_string);
    return str_replace($dirty, $clean, $encrypted_string);
}

function decrypt($encrypted_string) { 
    $dirty = array("+", "/", "=");
    $clean = array("_PLUS_", "_SLASH_", "_EQUALS_");

    $string = base64_decode(str_replace($clean, $dirty, $encrypted_string));

    $decrypted_string = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $_SESSION['encryption-key'],$string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $_SESSION['iv']);
    return $decrypted_string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, str_replace idea was great !!

Comment: mcrypt_get_iv_size(), mcrypt_create_iv(), mcrypt_encrypt() and mcrypt_decrypt()  are all deprecated in php7.1 to onwards.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using Base64 for encoding your data you can also use [Base32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32) (RFC 4648) which is URL-safe because it only uses letters A–Z (case-insensitive) and the digits 2–7. There is already a [PHP library](https://github.com/ChristianRiesen/base32) for encoding/decoding. Note that Base32 takes ~20% more space than Base64.

You can also use [URLcrypt](https://github.com/atrapalo/URLcrypt) which is a handy library helping you with encryption and Base32 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Encryption {
    var $skey   = "SuPerEncKey2010"; // you can change it

    public  function safe_b64encode($string) {

        $data = base64_encode($string);
        $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function safe_b64decode($string) {
        $data = str_replace(array('-','_'),array('+','/'),$string);
        $mod4 = strlen($data) % 4;
        if ($mod4) {
            $data .= substr('====', $mod4);
        }
        return base64_decode($data);
    }

    public  function encode($value){ 

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $text = $value;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this-&gt;skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($this-&gt;safe_b64encode($crypttext)); 
    }

    public function decode($value){

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $crypttext = $this-&gt;safe_b64decode($value); 
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this-&gt;skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($decrypttext);
    }
}
```