# How to make secure data transfer using PHP GET method

Tags: php, arrays, json, get

In  my application I have used `GET method` to send `data` over `URL` in many places. I think it is a `not secure` way to send data over the `URL`. Just the data are showing in `URL`.

Ex:

```
<a href="check_appointments.php?user=<?php echo $_GET['userid'] ?>&p_id=<?php echo $_GET['pid'] ?>">  </a>
```

I want to transfer data in `secure` way. Is there any way to `hide` these information or any `encryption` method to follow. Please someone help me to improve my codes. Any help may highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP sending encrypted data via the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014118/php-sending-encrypted-data-via-the-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encode your data by base64_encode method. It will be encrypted when sending via url. base64_decode to see the decrypted data.

```
<a href="check_appointments.php?user=<?php echo base64_encode($_GET['userid']) ?>&p_id=<?php echo base64_encode($_GET['pid']) ?>">  </a>
```

Comment: Please do a sample for how to `send` and how to `recieve` ?

Comment: Here is the right answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript

Comment: Any PHP method to follow?

Comment: `$input = base64_encode($string)`
`$input = base64_decode($encodedstring)`

I have updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

use base64 encode is not the best way to send sensible data, this encoded data can be decoded with online decoders such as https://www.base64decode.org/, you must to use https protocol on your server to transfer sensible data and use a method like base64 encode just to "hide it".

Comment: Anything can be decoded for developers/hackers, i think its only for the user not to show the user IDs.

Comment: Luis has a point though. The question was for _secure_ data transfer. There is nothing secure about base64 encoding. Like the name says, it's encoding, not encryption.