# Trying to add a hash to a URL to prevent URL tampering, but "+" included therefore now get 404 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, .NET4.5, C#, Razor.

I have reused some very useful code, off Codeproject, from Albin, to prevent URL tampering, by adding a hash. Works well in the main.

However....

I now discovered that I am getting 404 error:

```
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

This I understand to be due to the inclusion of "+" in the url, which in my case is within the hash ie:

```
http://myServer/Controller/Action/Ivz7P+b2ZPmatG6kZaY_IR0az1s=?mode=xxx
```

The code for generating the hash is:

```
//Converting the salt in to a byte array
byte[] saltValueBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
//Encrypt the salt bytes with the password

 Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltValueBytes,2);
 //get the key bytes from the above process

 byte[] secretKey = key.GetBytes(16);
 //generate the hash

 HMACSHA1 tokenHash = new HMACSHA1(secretKey);

 tokenHash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringToToken));
 //convert the hash to a base64string
 token = Convert.ToBase64String(tokenHash.Hash).Replace("/", "_");
```

It seems that I need a way of generating hashes without "+" or replacing the "+"s, but that would invalidate the hash.

Best approach would be to generate hashes without "+"s.

Thoughts.

EDIT1

It seems if I take the UrlToken out of the routing and therefore have it appended at the end of the URL ie:

```
http://myServer/Controller/Action?mode=xxx&urltoken=Ivz7P+b2ZPmatG6kZaY_IR0az1s=
```

It now works. Not sure why. Well the 404 goes away, but the URL tampering mechanism now fails all the time !! May not be related.

EDIT2

I have now got this working by altering the URL tampering code to extract the hash from the non route bit ie after "?". This all works fine, and as I understand it I have not opened any new vulnerabilities as I have kept the default ASP.NET settings.

EDIT3

See:

[Hex Code Convertion](https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/3021045)

Comment: you need a url-friendly hash. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url) answer, it suggests to replace [+/=] chars with [-_~], which will work for path. Another approach would be not to use base-64 encode, and use raw hex-encoded sha value (of course, this will make url longer)

Comment: ALexander, thanks for this. Interesting. What would the hex encoding code look like. My current Base64 convertion is "Convert.ToBase64String(tokenHash.Hash);"

Comment: Added HEX code as EDIT3 from generous online contribution.

Comment: In your case, simplest hex conversion would be HMACSHA1 s = ...; BitConverter.ToString(s.Hash).Replace("-", "");

Comment: Alexander, if you can put this as an answer then I can mark it up. I ended up with ?HexedHash as the answer with "correct" routes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS7 request filter rejects URLs containing + characters. You can disable it by adding this to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

or you can encode '+' to '%20' by:
`System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(string str)`

Comment: I think the problem with this is that you then open up other vulnerabilities such as code injection attacks. See EDIT2 for my final answer

Comment: Not sure if you can replace "+" with "%20" as this would invalidate the hash ie "+" is different to "%20" as far as the hash verification is concerned.

Comment: Decode the url with `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode` then use it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I don't get any down votes here, but I had issues while sending this kind of special data to some POS Terminals (Verifone, Hypercom, and Ingenico).

The way to fix it, was escaping the URL (or your hash/anti tampering stuff) using "HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode" and to read it, ".URLDecode". This encoded special characters and made them easily transportable.

So you may need to generate your links using this function.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope it helps you