# How to pass URL with parameter, as a parameter?

Tags: php, get

I'm trying to pass a URL as a parameter, but that URL also has parameters. Of course these parameters are important and must be transmitted and properly interpreted.

For example : 
http://example.com/myclicktrackingscript.php?source=sidebar&url=http://example.com/redirect_to.php?site=site1

(yes I know, I could click track and redirect all at once in one file, but in some specific situations, I just can't : sometimes I need to pass whatever URL with parameters AS a parameter)

So far i've used URL rewriting :
http://example.com/redirect_to.php?site=site1 => http://example.com/redirect/site1/

.. but that's not very handy (too many specific situations where I need more flexibility)

**Is there a better way to do that ?**

My guess is maybe hashing the parameter URL :

For example : http://example.com/myclicktrackingscript.php?source=sidebar$url=REJREJ12333232rerereE

... but how to "dehash" it properly ?

I've never used such technique, has anyone any examples / tips / advice about how to do so ?

Thanks

Comment: Simply use base64 encoding and decoding, encode your url with base64 and decode it when ever you need.

Comment: @GTSSoft. base64-encoding will, however, lose any form of "human readability" - this may or may not be good

Comment: But why you want to allow user to read your query string? is there any specific requirement?

Comment: Actually, for the project i'm working on, I like the idea of making it "non human readable". I think i'll go with base64_encode, but I got the point with urlencode as well, thanks to you all, that was fast and effective (as usual in here)

Comment: Although I read here that using base64_encode might be unsafe ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url
=> Should I use urlencode on top of base64_encode ?

Answer (score 7):

You should just encode parameter:

```
urlencode('http://example.com/redirect_to.php?site=site1')
```

And encoded value will be: `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fredirect_to.php%3Fsite%3Dsite1`

Comment: So simple, thanks. Do I need to urldecode it after that ?

Comment: @Baptiste nope, it will be decoded automatically for you

Answer (score 2):

While `urlencode` will work, it is also results in *messy* (looking, IMOHO) output for this task by default. However, it can be cleaned up!

This is because [some "special characters" are allowed in a *query string*](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201008/what_characters_are_allowed_unencoded_in_query_strings/), thus we can fix the over-encoding to make it look prettier.

```
$encoded = urlencode('http://target.com/foo_bar.php?a=1&b=2');
// Remove unneeded encoding
$encoded = str_replace('%3A', ':', $encoded);
$encoded = str_replace('%2F', '/', $encoded);
$encoded = str_replace('%3F', '?', $encoded);
$encoded = str_replace('%3D', '=', $encoded);
// There are several additional characters that need not be encoded in
// the query string; refer to the link.
```

This works *when* $encoded is used in the query portion of the URI.

```
$url = "http://blah/?url=$encoded";
```

And should result in a fairly-readable URL like the following. Note the & in the embedded URL is still encoded as it denotes termination between value pairs.

```
http://blah/?url=http://target.com/foo_bar.php?a=1%26b=2
```

---

Where human readability is not desired there are also approaches such as base64-encoding the the URL (which [must still be made URI-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)) or using a backend to provide a URL-shortener service (which would allow "http://blah.com/?afjnD" style URLs).

However, hashing by itself will not work because (unless the mapping is persisted) the hash function is a one-way operation and the original data is not recoverable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `urlencode`

```
 $parmeter_url = "http://example.com/redirect_to.php?site=site1";
 $parmeter_url = urlencode($parmeter_url);
 $url = "http://example.com/myclicktrackingscript.php?source=sidebar&url=".$parmeter_url;
 echo $url;
```

see **[Demo](https://eval.in/172062)**