# URL contain % ,%2f would be a / and the %3d a = In yii?

Tags: php, url, encryption, yii, yii-url-manager

My url in yii is:

```
http://localhost/php_pro_106/reload/ByCustomer/mJYwIzoaIGe0R8lAVCqPhG%2Fg0jJFWjiWWdPnkq5VDlY%3D
```

what should I have to do in url manager to get this,My current rule is:

```
'<controller:\w+>/ByCustomer/<giftcode>'=>'<controller>/ByCustomer',
```

Actually problem is that I get :

```
The requested URL     /php_pro_106/reload/ByCustomer/mJYwIzoaIGe0R8lAVCqPhG/g0jJFWjiWWdPnkq5VDlY= was     not found on this server.
```

**It is due to `%3D` `%2F` in the URL.What I have to do to make it work fine?**

Comment: @Blubberguy22 I dont know .But it is encrypt form of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know apache has problem with `%2F` in URL, it will always reply with 404, php script is not executed. I never found a way around it. But that was some years ago.

EDIT:

There's a solution, but it requires you can edit apache configuration file for your virtual host at least (I didn't have that at that time). Then you have to add `AllowEncodedSlashes On` inside your `<VirtualHost>`. Or you can also set it globaly.

Comment: I did not use this , I have posted my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of it,For that I have to change my encode and decode method:

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
 return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```

The problem was due to some characters which are there in encoded Url.So, I have to replace these characters.

These links Help me:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url/5835352#5835352)

and

[google Group](https://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=3046)