# How to decode JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring

This question is related with my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577922/how-to-pass-a-json-array-as-a-parameter-in-url)

I can successfully get the String in json format from the URL to my spring controller

Now I have to decode it

so I did like the following

```
@RequestMapping("/saveName")
@ResponseBody
public String saveName(String acc)
{jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try
    {
   System.out.println(acc);
    org.json.JSONObject convertJSON=new org.json.JSONObject(acc);

    org.json.JSONObject  newJSON = convertJSON.getJSONObject("nameservice");
    System.out.println(newJSON.toString());
    convertJSON = new org.json.JSONObject(newJSON.toString());
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("id"));

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();jsonObject.accumulate("result", "Error Occured ");
    }
    return jsonObject.toString();
}
```

This is the JSON String `{ "nameservice": [ { "id": 7413, "name": "ask" }, { "id": 7414, "name": "josn" }, { "id": 7415, "name": "john" }, { "id": 7418, "name": "RjhjhjR" } ] }`

When I run the code then I get the error

```
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["nameservice"] is not a JSONObject.
```

What wrong I am doing?

Comment: nameservice is JSONArray [ ] indicates JSONArray

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer working with the entire string and then writing parsing logic? Perhaps you should read http://codetutr.com/2013/04/09/spring-mvc-easy-rest-based-json-services-with-responsebody/

Comment: @hofan41 Thanks for suggesting,Android guys will send me data using this format and I have store id and name in the DB.So I am converting the JSON String to JSON Object and then decoding it.If you have other ways then Please post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a `JSONObject`, it's a `JSONArray`

From your question:

```
{ "nameservice": [ { "id": 7413, "name": "ask" }, { "id": 7414, "name": "josn" }, { "id": 7415, "name": "john" }, { "id": 7418, "name": "RjhjhjR" } ] }
```

The `[` after the nameservice key tells you it's an array. It'd need to be a `{` to indicate an object, but it isn't

So, change your code to use it as a `JSONArray`, then iterate over the contents of that to get the `JSONObjects` inside it, eg

```
JSONArray nameservice = convertJSON.getJSONArray("nameservice");
for (int i=0; i<nameservice.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject details = nameservice.getJSONObject(i);
   // process the object here, eg
   System.out.println("ID is " + details.get("id"));
   System.out.println("Name is " + details.get("name"));
}
```

See the [JSONArray javadocs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer,Can you please tell me how will I get the name and ids?

Comment: You need to iterate over the array, fetching out the JSONObjects from that. See edit

Comment: If I were given `[ { "id": 7413, "name": "ask" }, { "id": 7414, "name": "josn" }, { "id": 7415, "name": "john" }, { "id": 7418, "name": "RjhjhjR" } ]` then How to do.Please tell me

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're trying to get a JSONObject when "nameservice" is an array of JSONObjects and not an object itself. You should try this:

```
JSONObject json    = new JSONObject(acc);
JSONArray  jsonarr = json.getJSONArray("nameservice");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject nameservice = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
  String id   = nameservice.getString("id");
  String name = nameservice.getString("name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you do it manualy if you already have Spring Framework.

Take a look at [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html) and configure your ServletDispatcher accordingly. Spring will automatically convert your objects to JSON string and vice versa.

After that your controller method will be looked like:

```
@RequestMapping("/saveName")
@ResponseBody
public Object saveName(@RequestBody SomeObject obj) {
    SomeObject newObj = doSomething(obj);
    return newObj;
}
```

Comment: sorry I did not understand how to do

Comment: Try to investigate this example, because it's the common approach for your issue: http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program