# Swift and Alamofire API calls: trouble reading parameters

Tags: json, swift, api, alamofire

I am using Alamofire 4 and Swift 4. I am attempting to make an API request that is passed 1 parameter called `Body` which is a JSON string. The JSON string should look like this:

```
{
    "BirthDate": "1985-02-08",
    "GivenName": "mary",
    "FamilyName": "lee",
    "LicenceNumber": "94977000",
    "StateOfIssue": "ACT"
}
```

My code is returning the following result in the debug console:

```
{
  "result" : {
    "statuscode" : "400",
    "error" : [
      "GivenName needs to be a string",
      "FamilyName needs to be a string",
      "BirthDate needs to be a string",
      "LicenceNumber needs to be a string",
      "StateOfIssue needs to be a string",
      "MiddleName needs to be a string",
      "GivenName needs a value",
      "FamilyName needs a value",
      "BirthDate needs a value",
      "LicenceNumber needs a value",
      "StateOfIssue needs a value"
    ]
  }
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
public func testApi(){

    let headers = ["token":self.APIkey, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
    let url = self.testApiUrl

    let bodyString : String = "{\"BirthDate\":\"1985-02-08\",\"GivenName\":\"mary\",\"FamilyName\":\"lee\",\"LicenseNumber\":\"94977000\",\"StateOfIssue\":\"ACT\"}"
    let params : [String:String] = ["Body":"\(bodyString)"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let apiResponse = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                print("params is \(params)")
                if apiResponse["exceptionId"] as? String == nil {

                    print(apiResponse)

                    return
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Could someone please help? I have tried breaking down the Body string to a dictionary level (e.g. `Body: [name:Mary ... etc]`) but this did not work either, and the API docs say it should be passed 1 parameter called Body which is a string.

Comment: @Skype Dunworth check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
public func testApi(){

    //replace "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" with "application/json"
    //let headers = ["token":self.APIkey, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

    let headers = ["token":self.APIkey, "Content-Type": "application/json"]
    let url = "https://sandbox.rapidid.com.au/dvs/driverLicence"

    let bodyString: [String: Any] = [
        "BirthDate": "1985-02-08",
        "GivenName": "mary",
        "FamilyName": "lee",
        "LicenceNumber": "94977000",
        "StateOfIssue": "ACT"
    ]
    //I think you don't want "Body" in request
    //let params : [String: Any] = ["Body": bodyString]

    //replace params with bodyString
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: bodyString, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let apiResponse = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                print("params is \(bodyString)")
                if apiResponse["exceptionId"] as? String == nil {
                    print(apiResponse)
                    return
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a POST request is made by passing JSON data, the data is passed in the body.

> ...API docs say it should be passed 1 parameter called Body which is a string

If I understand correctly then the API is expecting JSON Data in the body of the post request.

Looks like you haven't encoded the JSON correctly. Here's how to fix it...

```swift
public func testApi() {

    let headers = ["token":self.APIkey, "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
    let url = self.testApiUrl

    let bodyString: [String: Any] = [
        "BirthDate": "1985-02-08",
        "GivenName": "mary",
        "FamilyName": "lee",
        "LicenceNumber": "94977000",
        "StateOfIssue": "ACT"
    ]
    let params : [String: Any] = ["Body": bodyString]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let apiResponse = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                print("params is \(params)")
                if apiResponse["exceptionId"] as? String == nil {
                    print(apiResponse)
                    return
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this fixes it.
However if you need to pass the JSON as a parameter then you need to encode it into the URL. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577922/how-to-pass-a-json-array-as-a-parameter-in-url) for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. That returned the same error response. I will try looking the suggested URL encoding you have suggested

Comment: Actually not all your params are String. Some expect value, make sure you aren't accidentally making everything String.

Comment: It is saying both that they all need to be a string and that they all need a value. hmm.