# How to set json array in url with get method in android?

Tags: android, httprequest

```
http://192.168.0.14/something/storeAnswerGet?longitude=20.49158053365199&latitude=44.798944935485885&answers="[{\"id\":3,\"id_question\":7,\"user_id\":1,\"answer\":\"Beograd\"},{\"id\":3,\"id_question\":7,\"user_id\":1,\"answer\":\"Valjevo\"},{\"id\":3,\"id_question\":8,\"user_id\":1,\"answer\":\"Da\"}]"
```

Problem is after `&answers=` it is not recognized as part of url,
that is a formatted `JsonObject` in string.

Comment: You have to convert it to a string and then append it in the url.

Comment: How do you concatenate the URL string?

Comment: Thank for your answers, i have solved this problem by placing a string in Uri.encode (jsonStringArray). And URL looks "http://192.168.0.14/storeAnswerGet?&answers="+ Uri.encode(jsonStringArray)

Comment: have you try: ..&answers="+URLEncoder.encode(json_here)

Comment: Uri.encode works fine for me, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27578923/1088975

Basically you have 2 options

1. Send data with `POST` method
2. Encode text and send with `GET`

Answer (score 0):

Basically `storeAnswer` shall be `post` request and `payload` to be added on the request `body` with `json` format.

```
public void sendAnswerRequest(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.14/something/storeAnswerGet");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("latitude", 44.798944935485885);
        jsonParam.put("longitude", 20.49158053365199);

        JSONArray answers = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject answer = new JSONObject();
        answer.put("id",3);
        answer.put("id_question",7);
        answer.put("user_id",1);
        answer.put("answer","Beograd");

        answers.put(answer); // Add all answers to answer array..

        jsonParam.put("answers",answers);

        Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        //os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(), "UTF-8"));
        os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());

        os.flush();
        os.close();

        Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
        Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());

        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```