# retrieve an array of from vuejs and add it to session variable

Tags: java, session, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm stuck with a problem:

1. i have an array of object in vuejs
   `TablePlayers[]
   this.TablePlayers.push({'message': this.returnmsg, 'player': true, 'Time': time});`
2. i send it to my java controller with:

`axios.get("http://localhost:8080/SetTablePlayers/"+this.TablePlayers)`

then i add this table of object to java session with :
`HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("TablePlayers", TablePlayers);`

3.and when i would get this object from session :

```
TablePlayers= (List<Players>)session.getAttribute("TablePlayers");
```

it returns `null`.
how can i fix that thanks, and this is right?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send your JSON data that way. Please use an http POST method and send the data into the body of the request.

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8080/SetTablePlayers/", this.TablePlayers)
```

of course you have to adapt also your server code.

GET method should be used to obtain something from the server instead.

Comment: Obviously, I'm talking about convention https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
but if you want absolutely send the JSON data via GET I suggest you to read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577922/how-to-pass-a-json-array-as-a-parameter-in-url