# PHP Fetching encrypted value from addressbar not correct

Tags: php, url, encryption

Hi I Have a mailer that has a link to my site along that link is an encrypted data, the main problem is the fetching part if my encrypted data has a "+" sign it is not included on the data that was fetched see here for example of the data:

```
index.php?s=NER4gXPSuaads+Cmb8LANA==
```

this is the link that has the + sign
but from my firebase console 
[image]
as you can see the "+" sign is no longer there instead it was changed into a white space. 
I have read some articles about php's [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it says there that all Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character. So I was thinking that it could be related to that.. is there a solution for this?

Here is how I tried fetching it for your reference

```
    if($_GET['s']!='success') {
   $ref =htmlspecialchars($_GET['s']);
} else {
   $ref = "direct";
}
```

also additional Info the encryption was on AES.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: base64_encode on output (in your view), base64_decode on input (your controller).

Comment: Use `urlencode()` before dumping strings into URLs.

Comment: @cerebriform I used your idea about using base64_encode and decode and it was exactly what I was looking for although I'm not sure if how I did it was the proper way.. But still thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I have managed to find out what I'm looking for thanks to @cerebriform's comment

Here is how I did it

```
$refenc = base64_encode($refence);
```

`$refence` is the result of the AES encryption so before sending it as a mail It was encoded again but this time using `base64_encode()`. So how it looks like, I'll show you `$final = base64_encode($rdfence);`. Then after that it will be sent to the email whichever my mailer wishes to send it to.. How my site manages to eliminate my problem is upon retrieving the link from the url I used `base64_decode()` ... Then after its been decoded another decoder will take place the AES decryption script will now decrypt it to obtain the raw data from the database

here is the final Code:

```
  if($_GET['s']!='success') {
 $d = base64_decode($_GET['s']);
 $aes->setData($d);
 $ref=$aes->decrypt();

} else {
   $ref = "No Id";
}
```

Thanks for the input guys

Comment: Pretty much.  Base 64 still allows for + to occur, but it occurs with predictable frequency.  To bullet-proof your application, follow the [advice in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5835352/2908724).

Answer (score 4):

To set and fetch "s" properly you need to urlencode() it when you set it on the URL and urldecode() it when you fetch it.

It looks to me like "s" possibly has not been URL encoded when set on the URL.