# How can I base64_encode and base64_decode string with html tags?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, base64

I have a problem with base64 decode
For example, I have this code:

```
else if($_POST['submit']==2){
        $send = base64_encode($text_success);
        wp_redirect( home_url('/sales-funnel/add-product?msg='.$send) ); exit;
    }
```

I send encoded string to page, so that user can't simply read it from url.
$text_success contain html code, which is generated if `$wpdb->query` not contain errors:

```
 `Darījums veiksmīgi pievienots!</br>Komentārs veiksmīgi pievienots!</br>Klients veiksmīgi pievienots!</br>Fāze ir pievienota! </br>`
```

In all online base64_decode it's works great, but my WordPress site return empty string when I'm trying to do:

```
if (isset($_GET['msg']) && !empty($_GET['msg'])){
    $text = base64_decode($_GET['msg']);
    echo $text;
}
```

But, `$_GET['msg'] = RGFyxKtqdW1zIHZlaWtzbcSrZ2kgcGlldmllbm90cyE8L2JyPktvbWVudMSBcnMgdmVpa3NtxKtnaSBwaWV2aWVub3RzITwvYnI+S2xpZW50cyB2ZWlrc23Eq2dpIHBpZXZpZW5vdHMhPC9icj5GxIF6ZSBpciBwaWV2aWVub3RhISA8L2JyPg==`

P.S. I tried to use it without html tags, all works great.

Comment: I had a likely problem once and it appears that WP uses a security callback to prevent usage of html tags to prevent injections. But I strongly disadvise to disable such securities and more generally to use $_GET to retrieve html content for your page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that the base64 alphabet is not URL-safe. In this particular case, your base64-encoded string contains a `+`, which is interpreted as a space.

To solve this, you can either:

- Use a URL-safe version of the base64 alphabet, i.e. replacing `+` with `-`, `/` with `_`, and trimming the trailing `=` paddding, as described in [RFC4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835352/3558960) includes a code sample for this approach.
- URL-encode your content after base64 encoding, turning `+` into `%2B`, `/` into `%2F`, and `=` into `%3D`.

This should solve your problem, but it goes without saying that in an untrusted environment, giving users the ability to inject raw HTML into your site constitutes a serious security risk.