# JWT decode includes unwanted html tags

Tags: php, tags, base64, decode, jwt

im usin the following php function to return the value of the 'uid' claim in the payload of a jwt:

```js
function isLoggedIn($headers)
 {
  $ret = false;
  if (!empty($headers['Authorization']))
                {
                  $parts = explode('.', $headers['Authorization']);
                  echo base64_decode($parts[1]);
                  return 7; //currently set a 7 just function 
                }
    }
```

the string returned in

```
    echo base64_decode($parts[1]);
```

has html tags included

```
    <br />"iss": "www.thetenticle.com",<br />"iat": "1449405778",<br />"nbf": "1449405838",<br />"exp": "1449492238",<br />"uid": "batman"<br />}
```

i dont want this because i need to find out what is in the value of 'uid'.
what am i doing wrong?

ps i know there is more to handling a jwt than this, but for now i just need to get the id of the logged in in user.

i essentially need an array of claims

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32328927/1114204) on SO:

> The problem is related to the fact that the base64 alphabet is not URL-safe. In this particular case, your base64-encoded string contains a +, which is interpreted as a space.

Code from [php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/src/JWT.php) to safely decode the input:

```
public static function urlsafeB64Decode($input) {
    $remainder = strlen($input) % 4;
    if($remainder) {
        $padlen = 4 - $remainder;
        $input .= str_repeat('=', $padlen);
    }
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}
```