# Can't convert UTF-8 'ø' to ASCII

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii

Function converts all other characters, just 'ø' what is UTF-8 character not, all other chars, like "Ч,Č,Ć,Đ,Š,Ž,Ђ,Ж,Љ" etc. converts normally to ascii...

This is function what i use:

```
function toAscii($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/()_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
    return $clean;
}
```

I need it to ascii for url.

Comment: You can base64 encode anything for URL

Comment: How do you mean ? If i use base64_encode i will convert Tromsø IL to something like VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw== ? I want just 
tromso. ø=>o

Comment: What is your encoding set to? When I run `toAscii("Ч,Č,Ć,Đ,Š,Ž,Ђ,Ж,Љ", array(), '-');` I receive "Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string ", but when I run `toAscii("ø", array(), '-');` it converts to an "o"

Comment: I select data from database where are UTF-8 characters. 
Intersting, that characters what are "illegal" it converts normally...

Comment: You might try mb_detect_encoding($string) on that database data to verify what you have coming in.

Comment: Yes i did that, ASCII and UTF8 are. Tromsø IL is UTF-8, how is possible when i toAscii('Tromsø IL'); it returns me tromso-il, but when i 
toAscii($row['local']) from db than is troms-il... How is that possible O.O When i echo $row['local'] it is Tromsø IL, with UTF-8 as mb_detect, when i try to strpos($str,'ø') it won't recognise character, have you idea what might be a problem?

Comment: Just for kicks, try  mb_strpos(($str,'ø'). You should loop through the db string and echo the ord() for each character. If you don't know how to do this, I can post an example.

Comment: Nope, mb_strpos won't work.. Please give me an example?

Comment: Yes, you will get base-64 encoded string that you will decode to get the data

Comment: @T.S. Please can you show me an example? ord of whole string returns me 84114111109115195184327376 when i try using ascii converter to compare i see that end is different look:
084 114 111 109 115 195 184 032 073 076
327376 is from php,  073 076 is end in this converter http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/5835352/1704458

Comment: For passing in url, i would advise the same as T.S.. On the other end use base64_decode to convert it back

Comment: If i use it in begin in toAscii function i get same:

 $str = base64_url_encode($str);
 $str = base64_url_decode($str);
 $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
 $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
 $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
 $clean = preg_replace("/[\/()_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
 return $clean;

Comment: You don't need to use your function at all. Just url_encode before passing as a url and then url_decode. You then have your string untouched. This handles your stated need: "I need it to ascii for url."

Comment: I think that is different ASCII value of 'ø' from database and 'ø' what ASCII accepts...  When i replace toAscii function to just 
$str = base64_url_encode($str);
$str = base64_url_decode($str);
Than i get in url question diamonds...

Comment: see: [utf8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

The iconv "transliterate to ascii" function is unreliable. There isn't always a universal transliteration or a transliteration that makes sense from any arbitrary unicode codepoint to ascii. There isn't a unicode standard saying how to do it (although at one point there was a draft one, it was abandoned as unsuccessful). So, anyway, there isn't a reliable way to do this, or the iconv function isn't one. Just how it goes.

As others have commented, there is a standard way to put unicode into a URL though. Trying to transliterate arbitrary unicode codepoints to ascii is unlikely to be the right solution to your problem; even for the transliteration that is happening, you are likely losing meaning.