# How to decode data from base64 with utf-8 charset encoding in php

Tags: php, xml, base64

I have an xml file with dynamic contents like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <tracks>
    <idx>0</idx>
    <path>/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/Worth It - Fifth Harmony - ft. Kid Ink.mp3</path>
  </tracks>
  <tracks>
    <idx>1</idx>
    <path>/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/Flashlight - Jessie J.mp3</path>
  </tracks>
  <tracks>
    <idx>2</idx>
    <path>/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/価値がある.mp3</path>
  </tracks>
</config>
```

And also a php file which creates another xml file according to data fetch on first xml. Here's a piece of code in generating new xml:

```
$item = $xml->addChild('tracks');
$item->addChild('artist', base64_encode($mp3Artist));
$item->addChild('song_name', base64_encode($mp3Title));
$item->addChild('song_path', base64_encode($file)); 
$item->addChild('album', base64_encode($mp3Album));
```

However, when I encode `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/価値がある.mp3`

the output is `L21udC9IRC9IRF9hMi9teW11c2ljL+S+oeWApOOBjOOBguOCiy5tcDM=` which is when I decode it again, the value becomes `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/ä¾¡å€¤ãŒã‚ã‚‹.mp3`
but when I decode it on this site https://www.base64decode.org/ with utf-8 encoding, the output is the same as the first one which is `/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/価値がある.mp3`

So my question is, how can I achieved utf-8 encoding on php's `base64_encode` to output the exactly the same as on www.base64decode.org? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything just use `base64_decode` :

```
$encoded = base64_encode("/mnt/HD/HD_a2/mymusic/価値がある.mp3");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF" ;//Optionally add this line if you want to force a program to read as utf-8
echo $encoded." <br />";
$decoded = base64_decode($encoded);
echo $decoded;
```

And optionally add a `echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF" ;` on the first output line if you want to force a file to be interpreted as utf-8 by any program

Comment: I examine my codes again and I see where the error occurs, the encoded path is used to url but when the browser detects `+` on string, it converts it to `%20` in my code, this `L21udC9IRC9IRF9hMi9teW11c2ljL+S+oeWApOOBjOOBguOCiy5tcDM=` will become `L21udC9IRC9IRF9hMi9teW11c2ljL%20S%20oeWApOOBjOOBguOCiy5tcDM=` and the result is 404 not found

Comment: I just found the solution to my problem above, thanks to this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url