# PHP mcrypt same key + base64 + urlencode = different values

Tags: php, encryption, base64, urlencode

I am trying to use mcrypt to encrypt a value on one PHP site and decrypt it on another one. Sometimes it works (like 80% of the time), sometimes it doesn't work.
Now I found out that the encrypted text is different when encrypting the same values with the same key. How is this possible?
What am I missing?

Here is the code for encryption:

```
# key is always the same
$key = "mysimplekey";

# text is always the same
$plaintext = "text_to_encrypt";

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

$ciphertext = $iv . $ciphertext;

$ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);
$ciphertext_url = rawurlencode($ciphertext_base64);

# gives different values for the same key & encryption text:                    
echo $ciphertext_url;
```

Code for decryption:

```
$key = 'mysimplekey';

$ciphertext_dec = base64_decode($_REQUEST['u']);
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

# retrieves the IV, iv_size should be created using mcrypt_get_iv_size()
$iv_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, 0, $iv_size);

# retrieves the cipher text (everything except the $iv_size in the front)
$ciphertext_dec = substr($ciphertext_dec, $iv_size);

# may remove 00h valued characters from end of plain text
$ciphertext_dec = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext_dec, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec));
```

Comment: URL's have a maximum input (i believe 2048), can  this be the cause?

Comment: `$iv` - you're generating new initialization vector every time

Comment: Yes but the vector is prepended to the string and this should not be the problem for decryption should it? But yeah technically you're right my question was asked in a wrong way.

Comment: how decryptor will know what part of final url is iv and what is text?

Comment: How are you constructing the URL to send to the decryption script?  If you are doing it in javascript, something may be adding an additional layer of encoding.

Comment: Easy mode: Don't implement it yourself, just use [a secure encryption library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption).

Comment: @ChrisRive the URL is constructed in PHP, simply something like echo 'link.com/site.html?parameter1=xyz&u='. $ciphertext_url;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo.

The problem was apparently nothing I mentioned in the question itself.
I am sorry.

Standalone this should work like @ChrisRibe tested out in his answer.

The problem in this particular case - which I didn't mention in my question - was, that the whole URL was ALSO urlencoded because it was passed as a PARAMETER onto another url (namely an html2pdf.it server). Therfor it worked if the encrypted, base64-encoded text had no special url reserved characters in it - but of course did not work if there were any url reserved characters!

Solution:

Instead of using rawurlencode for the base64-encoded encrypted text I now replace the 3 symbols which cause problems with urls with my own function, like answered in this stackoverflow question:
[Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
 return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_~');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
 return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_~', '+/='));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the combination of rawurlencode() and the decoding done by PHP to populate the $_REQUEST array are mangling your ciphertext/iv.

Update: I tested your code and it is working as expected in my implementation. Perhaps the encoded text is being modified on the client side in your implementation.

Comment: I don't see `rawurldecode` in OP's code, so this might be it.

Comment: I had rawurldecode() in the decoding before and it made no difference. The text won't be modified on the client side, since it is just embeded as url parameter into a link of the page. This link then links to the page which does the decryption. It's only because on the first page I have a user login value which I don't have on the second page, but need to pass to it to make sure the user is authorized to access the content.