# SHA1 with non-standard characters

Tags: hash, payment, sha1

I'm implementing an online payment system : Paybox.

I've got an autoresponse (between servers) and a response (attached to my customer when he is returning to my website.

Everything's good except for the signature which is a SHA1.
On the autoresponse side I have a valid sign:

```
ahkjqBWxsi2rMXWpQr9LaQFelTIGJ93pKfGt2E6lT1sIKABsNanexC0gZvt5Z8ShgQXUsGBS10QVPzUxmYDhWpuDKIiHDZ5i9mLm2UGz8LOJeGkIlikuXOCC3ny
```

However, with the customer (me for this test), I have:

```
ah8R%2F2mvvpc8Jo016XyO7WZbqmQktb%2BShME6A0X3hwCNWkkGXb1YI9wIS7RSCK1IJKotbYni8BxBNoHTKcLxdA9nOQPcQSD%2FUM3%2BdiptrnTuLZ1jP9bIDCvDtSav7WG509gw5PbEztpl5lOZlnIFuCMzC3Ps%2B2Rt%2FO6PSZfHgvA%3D
```

I don't understand :

1) Why are they différent.

2) Why does the second have '%' characters which can not be output from a SHA1

I thought about a different encoding but nothing so far, any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`%2F` and `%2B` are URL encoded characters; `/` and `+` respectively.

You likely see them because they can appear in a Base64 encoded string and thats what you appear to have (despite their absence in the 1st example) given that you cannot represent a raw SHA1 hash as a string.

In many scenarios you cannot use HTTP to send a string containing those characters in their raw form as they have special meaning, see [Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url).

Assuming functioning encoding/decoding and SHA1 code then the reason the two hashes are different is because the input data was different.

Comment: The problem is that these 2 strings should be the same, the method they are encoded with and the data used for encoding is the same according to the documentation...