# Base64 encoded String URL friendly

Tags: javascript, base64

I'm using this [function](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/qAGHT/) for `base64` decode/encode URL in `javascript` but i've seen many gives notice about making Base64 encoded String URL friendly and to use

```
// if this is your Base64 encoded string
var str = 'VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBhd2Vzb21lIHNjcmlwdA=='; 

// make URL friendly:
str = str.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_').replace(/\=+$/, '');

// reverse to original encoding
str = (str + '===').slice(0, str.length + (str.length % 4));
str = str.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magikmaker/7bjat/)

I see it only replce `+` with `-` and `\` with `_` so what is the point! i mean why should i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would not replace the characters they could get misinterpreted, like pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374794/4540647). This would result in either displaying wrong content or more likely displaying nothing.

For explanation:
In URLs the follwing characters are reserved: `: / ? # [ ] @ : $ & ' ( ) * + , ; =`

Like pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5835352/4540647) you need 65 characters to encode data, but the sum of uppercase-, lowercase characters and digits is only 62. So it needs three additional characters which are `+ = /`. These three are reserved. So you need to replace them. As of right now I am not entirely sure about `-`.