# Form data base64 encoded with get method

Tags: php, html, encoding, base64

I need to be able to provide custom URL's from html forms with the data encoded in base64.

For example:

```
<form name="test" action="test.php" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="category" />
 <input type="text" name="gender" />
 <input type="text" name="quantity" />
</form>
```

And get an URL:

```
test.php?Y2F0ZWdvcnk9c3BvcnRzJmdlbmRlcj1mZW1hbGUmcXVhbnRpdHk9NTA=
```

Thanks.

Comment: The function is called [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/base64_encode)... :-?

Comment: I know @ÁlvaroGonzález, but how do you encode all the values of the form as one string, and not as separated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably post the form first and then do the following:

```
// Sanitize data

$urlData = $array();

$urlData['category'] = $_POST['category'];
$urlData['gender']   = $_POST['gender'];
$urlData['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

$urlData = base64_encode( json_encode( $urlData ) );

header("Location test.php?data=". $urlData ."");
exit();
```

I used json_encode because base64 alone can alter the meaning of your data.
Checkout this article on that subject: [Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

Then on test.php:

```
$data = json_decode( base64_decode( $_GET['data'] ) );
// Sanitize data again
```

Comment: Given `method="get"`, `$_POST['...']` will just trigger an undefined index notice. And `json_encode()` will not generate the expected output format.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that `Y2F0ZWdvcnk9c3BvcnRzJmdlbmRlcj1mZW1hbGUmcXVhbnRpdHk9NTA=` is the expected output, we'll start by decoding it to see what it looks like:

```
category=sports&gender=female&quantity=50
```

That's exactly the query string of your GET form, so we can grab the value right from from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

The built-in function to encode is [base64_encode()](http://php.net/base64_encode) and we can concatenate strings with a [built-in operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) as well. Last not but least, we can encode a URL component with another built-in function called [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode). So we have all the bricks:

```
$url = 'test.php?' . rawurlencode(base64_encode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));
```

Comment: @ManelMusti What do you mean exactly? Is there anything wrong in my answer?

Comment: Not at all, your answer it's right and it has been very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use another array
just simple use this code

```
$codedData = base64_encode(json_encode($_POST));
$decodedData = json_decode(base64_decode($orderEncode) , true);
```