# Strange value when using Base64enconde and decode

Tags: php, html, base64

I m building an website and i'm using the base64encode() and base64decode().
I send the base64encode(value) through and url and i receive and then i decode the value. On the page that i have the decoded value i have one button that goes to the previous page and i use the encode to encode again the value and send it. the  previous page i decode that value and i encode again to send to the same page.

At the first time i receive the correct values but when i do more than 1 i get strange value. It is my code:

The first page:
Here i receive one value and i decode it.

```
$tablename = base64_decode($_GET['tablename']);
```

In the end of the page i have on list with this code, here i send the encoded value:

```
$descricao = base64_encode($row["descricao"]);
              $tablename = base64_encode($tablename);
              ?>
                <a href="./gestaoalarme.php?descricao=<?=$descricao?>&tablename=<?=$tablename?>">
```

In the seconde page i receive the encoded value

```
$tablename=base64_decode($_GET['tablename']);
```

and i have that button that goes back and send the encode value.

```
 <a href="./verdispositivos.php?tablename=<?=base64_encode($tablename)?>" class="btn Back btn-lg">
```

The first time results, but then not.

Comment: This seems db-related. If so; why do you feel the need to encode this? Anyone with intermediate PHP skills can decode that.

Answer (score 1):

[Base64 encoded values are not URL safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1374794/967168) due to the + / and = characters.

You will also need to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before using the string in a url.

E.g.

```
$value_to_encode = 'some=string/here+foobar';
$encoded = urlencode(base64_encode($value_to_encode));
$decoded = base64_decode(urldecode($encoded));
```

Comment: $value_to_encode  what should i put here? a variable or the url?

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves if this answer solved it, the question should be marked as solved. Also as I stated in comments: *"Anyone with intermediate PHP skills can decode that"* - so why the need to encode/decode this?

Comment: I was enconding only to not show the value in the link