# Getting 400 Bad Request, when trying to send base64 image string in query parameters?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post, base64

Trying to send base64 string for an image in the query param, and Getting 400 Bad Request.
Tried the following:-

Gone through this question on stack overflow.
According to this, chrome can have more characters in the URL than what I am sending as imageBytes(29527 characters),

[What is the maximum possible length of a query string ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)

Instructions in the following Question also didn't help

[Passing base64 encoded strings in URL ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

Here is my code

It works fine if i am sending a hard coded string like this "something" in place of form.imageBytes

```
$scope.submit = function(){
  var form = {};
  form.name = document.getElementById("recipient-name").value;
  form.desc = document.getElementById("message-text").value;
  form.owner = document.getElementById("message-text2").value;
  form.imageBytes = $scope.asdf;

  var data = JSON.stringify(form);

    debugger;
    var postString = "http://cos1plp:7030/tcw/interestgroup/addInterestGroups?name="+form.name+"&desc="+form.desc+"&owner="+form.owner+"&imageBytes="+form.imageBytes;

    $http.post(postString)

        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.headers = headers();
        console.log('Response Headers:' + headers());
        })

        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.headers = headers();
        });

}
```

Comment: Don't send it in the query string. You're sending a post for a reason, usually that reason is to send a post body and avoid the limitations of a query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Base64 strings can contain special characters, namely  `+ / =` signs. You'll need to encode them into a valid url string. Try adding this to your code:

```
data = data.replace(/\+/g, '%2B');
data = data.replace(/\//g, '%2F');
data = data.replace(/\=/g, '%3D');
```

Comment: Tried doing that manually and sending the request but it still fails.