# Download attached files from a Message Draft in Gmail API via PHP

Tags: php, gmail-api

The [official docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get) (*Messages.attachments.get*) are not very clear and they don't even mention PHP.

I am not looking for a copy/paste code but for some references that I can understand.

**Context**: I already understand OAuth2.0 and I am already sending e-mails successfully.

**Purpose**: I want to duplicate drafts. *(Download attached files and create new Draft)*

**What did I try?**

I accessed the draft and got the message id.

With that message id I fetch the attachment id.

With that attachment id I fetch the **message.attachment**, and get:

```
{
"size": 1793,
"data": "iVBORll...5CYII="
}
```

That "data" is the base64 encoded verison of the file, and I have the MIME Type too, so I am trying to process that.

This is the actual code of what I am doing:

```
$draft = $service->users_drafts->get('me', $draftId);

$borrador =  (array) $draft;

$protegido = chr(0).'*'.chr(0);

$MODELAZO=$borrador[$protegido.'modelData'];


$mensaje_id=$MODELAZO['message']['id'];


$adjuntos=$MODELAZO['message']['payload']['parts'];

echo '<h1>Parte Gorda Desmenuzada:</h1>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($adjuntos);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<h1>Archivos:</h1>';


// Qué mimetypes no son de archivos adjuntos
$mimetypezitos=array(
'image/png',
'image/jpeg',

'application/json',
'application/pdf',

'text/css'
);

foreach($adjuntos as $adjunto){
    $mimetype=$adjunto['mimeType'];

    if(in_array($mimetype,$mimetypezitos)){

        $filename=$adjunto['filename'];
        $attachmentId=$adjunto['body']['attachmentId'];

        echo '<h2>Adjunto: '.$mimetype.'</h2>';
        echo '<p>Nombre: '.$filename.'<p>'; 
        echo '<p>AttID: '.$attachmentId.'<p>';


        $q = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/'.$mensaje_id.'/attachments/'.$attachmentId.'?access_token='.$_SESSION['access_token']['access_token'];
        $blablason = json_decode(file_get_contents($q),true);

        $base64data=$blablason['data'];

        echo '<p>Data: '.$base64data.'<p>';

        echo '<p>Imagen: <img src="data:image/png;base64, '.$base64data.'" alt="Base 64 Imagen" /></p>';


    }


}
```

**And there is a slight issue going on**:

For the sake of testing, I am saving this info *(mimetype and base64data into a db)*.

On a new PHP file I grab them and do:

```
header("Content-type: ".$mimetype);
echo base64_decode($base64data);
```

All **images** do not work. *(Firefox displays black screen)*

I tried with other files (.css and .json) and they are working fine. *(Firefox displays the file as it originally was)*.

Comment: I have only played around with the PHP client library, but looking at [**the source**](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Gmail/Resource/UsersMessagesAttachments.php) has helped me a great deal.

Comment: @Tholle thanks, I updated my question with the progress I made so far.

Comment: The base64 data you get is url safe. Does it work if you decode it with a url safe version? I'm not aware of a reliable PHP url safe base64 decoder, but [**these answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url) might help?