# PHP decode a base64 encoded string which is url safe

Tags: php, base64, decoding

I need to decode a **base64** encoded string.

I need to do it with **PHP**.

The `base64_decode()` does not do the job.

I tried with:

`base64_decode(strtr($data, '-_,', '+/='));`

...it only works sometimes.

The same happens with:

`base64_decode(str_pad(strtr($data, '-_', '+/'), strlen($data) % 4, '=', STR_PAD_RIGHT));`

I really do not know how to approach this.

**UPDATE**:

The data comes from an [attached file via GMAIL API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316698/download-attached-files-from-a-message-draft-in-gmail-api-via-php).

I save it into the DB, *utf8mb4* TEXT field.

I do `mysqli -> real_escape_string()` before inserting.

Then I extract it from the DB as **$data**.

Comment: If it doesn't work with `base64_decode()` then it probably isn't a base64 encoded string. It might have been corrupted going through the pipe. Can you give an example and your expected output?

Comment: @ishegg I updated the question with more info.

Comment: I see. Is it not possible for you to provide an example of the bas64 encoded string? Otherwise it's a harder to help you in the dark.

Comment: [In the docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments) it says `a base64url encoded`, so if you can see `%3D` in the string, you only need to do `$attch = base64_decode(urldecode($in))` and thats it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks, I tried that one too. But it did not work neither. (Also, there are no `%3D` in the string)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still needed, but I had a base64 encoded string that itself was url encoded HTML. So the answer for me was to `urldecode()` AFTER doing `base64_decode()`.

This means wrapping the functions backwards:

`$html = urldecode(base64_decode($data))`