# Why sending base64encode string to ASP.NET WebAPI some character are auto-missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am posting a base64encode string to my asp.net-webapi such as "PHA+ZHNmYWFzZGYgZDxzcGFuIHN0eWxlPSJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiByZ2IoMjU1LCAyNTUsIDApOyI+c2FmYWRzZjwvc3Bhbj48L3A+"

But... the api only receives the string as following "PHA ZHNmYWFzZGYgZDxzcGFuIHN0eWxlPSJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiByZ2IoMjU1LCAyNTUsIDApOyI c2FmYWRzZjwvc3Bhbj48L3A " with '+' character repleced by ' '.

```
[Route("api/Test/TestFuncCall")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage TestFuncCall([FromBody] string input)
{
    JObject jo = JObject.Parse(input);
    string data = Convert.ToString(jo["data"]);
    string c = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(data));
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, c);
}
```

I've tried to add `<pages validateRequest="false"/>` to my web.config. But not working.

How to get the full base64encode string without any filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing base64 encoded strings in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url)

Comment: You need to url encode the string as there are characters in a base64 string that can be used in a URL e.g. '+', '='

Comment: Hi... But I am using HTTP POST Method Not GET...still need urlencode the post data payload?

Comment: Yes. The HttpMethod doesn't matter. Don't forget to Decode the string at the controller to convert it back to the original base64 string.

Comment: yes.... it works.... ..thx a lot...