# $_COOKIE replaced plus with space

Tags: php, cookies

I have a cookie set by C#.NET which I am reading in PHP.

Cookie name is MyCookie.

When I use echo `$_COOKIE['MyCookie'];`, it is printing cookie and replacing `+` with space.

The output is:

`n9JO1tpWznyWF5VQ/Oh4oFjJC9bJ4GFa4Onk4Av 8jcsc CtCFvsHQdDHiU0F1BE`

It should be

`n9JO1tpWznyWF5VQ/Oh4oFjJC9bJ4GFa4Onk4Av+8jcsc+CtCFvsHQdDHiU0F1BE`

I am not able to understand why that is the case and how to fix it. Because I need to decrypt this string first with AES algorithm. The decryption won't work as + is replaced with space.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374753/passing-base64-encoded-strings-in-url

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I didn't understand

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - I tried urlencode and it didn't work.

Comment: I have no control on C# setting cookie. I just have php to read cookie and it is not reading properly.

Comment: dang it ;p If you dont control the C# code, you only left with fixing it with something like str_replace https://3v4l.org/YlVhs

Comment: Thanks for the help, will use this.